# Angular, view not updating when changing model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm changing a model and I was expecting the view to update but it isn't:

Here is my view:

```
<div ng-controller="showCarCtrl">
                <h1>Damaged Cars</h1>
                <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                                <th>Plate Number</th>
                                <th>Brand</th>
                                <th>Color</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-show="car.damaged">
                                <td>{{car.plate_number}}</td>
                                <td>{{car.brand}}</td>
                                <td>{{car.color}}</td>
                                <td>
                                        <button ng-click="setRepaired(car.cid)">Repaired</button>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('showCarCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope,CarService){
$scope.setDamaged = function(cid){
                console.log("setting the car as damaged "+cid)
                $rootScope.loading = true;
                CarService.setDamageCar(cid)
                            .then(function(data){
                                $rootScope.loading = false;
                                console.log("set damage 1")
                                for(var i=0; i<$scope.cars.length; i++) {
                                        console.log("setting car as damage");
                                        if ($scope.cars[i]==cid) {
                                                $scope.cars[i].damaged = 1
                                                $scope.$apply();
                                                console.log("it enters here");
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        console.log($scope.cars)
                                }
                            },

                            //deferred
                            function(data){
                                console.log('Car Service failed');
                                $rootScope.loading = false;
                            });
        };

});
```

I've checked from the server, the reply from the server is properly comming and I'm successfully updating the model at `$scope.cars[i].damaged = 1`, the only issue is that I was expecting the view to change because as shown above, in the view, I've something as `<tr ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-show="car.damaged">`, but the view is not updating

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the binding but rather in the logic of your algorithm.

Comment: Use "===" instead of "==" in IF condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an error in your code here:

```
if ($scope.cars[i]==cid) {
```

Maybe it should be like this:

```
if ($scope.cars[i].cid === cid) {
```

Comment: It actually took me two plunks to notice this too :)

Comment: I think angular uses "===" instead of "=="